# Concatenation of awk outputs

Tags: sed, awk

I'm using regex to parse NMAP output. I want the ip addresses which are up with the corresponding ports open. Now I've a very naive method of doing that:

```
awk '/^Scanning .....................ports]/ {print substr ($2,1,15);}' results.txt
awk '/^[0-9][0-9]/ {print substr($1,1,4);}' results.txt | awk -f awkcode.awk
```

where awkcode.awk contains the code to extract numbers out of the substring.
The first line prints all the ips that are up and 2nd gives me the ports. My problem is that I want them mapped to each other. Is there any way to do that? Even a sed script would do.

Comment: It would help if you showed some output from your `nmap` command (or at least what options you're using).

Comment: you should provide details about the file (I could run nmap, but too lazy, and with which options?), and add awk and sed tag

Comment: yes, please supply the output and the requested output

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find using the "Grepable" output format to be easier to parse:

```
nmap -oG - -v -A 192.168.0.1-254
```

Sample output:

> Host: 192.168.1.1 (foo)      Status: Up
>   Host: 192.168.1.1 (foo)      Ports: 22/open/tcp//ssh//OpenSSH 5.1p1 Debian 6ubuntu2 (protocol 2.0)/, 80/open/tcp//http//Apache httpd 2.2.12 ((Ubuntu))/, 139/open/tcp//netbios-ssn//Samba smbd 3.X (workgroup: BAR)/, 445/open/tcp//netbios-ssn//Samba smbd 3.X (workgroup: BAR)/, 7100/open/tcp//font-service//X.Org X Font Server/     Ignored State: closed (995)

Or if you have an XML parser, use the XML output format:

```
nmap -oX - -v -A 192.168.0.1-254
```

Sample output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="file:///usr/share/nmap/nmap.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!-- Nmap 5.00 scan initiated Sun Jun 13 08:11:32 2010 as: nmap -oX - -v -A 192.168.1.1-254 -->
<nmaprun scanner="nmap" args="nmap -oX - -v -A 192.168.1.1-254" start="1276434692" startstr="Sun Jun 13 08:11:32 2010" version="5.00" xmloutputversion="1.03">
...
...
<host starttime="1276434692" endtime="1276434775"><status state="up" reason="syn-ack"/>
<address addr="192.168.1.1" addrtype="ipv4" />
<hostnames><hostname name="foo" type="PTR" /></hostnames>
<ports><extraports state="closed" count="995">
<extrareasons reason="conn-refused" count="995"/>
</extraports>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="22"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="ssh" product="OpenSSH" version="5.1p1 Debian 6ubuntu2" extrainfo="protocol 2.0" ostype="Linux" method="probed" conf="10" /><script id="ssh-hostkey" output="1024 1a:2b:4d:5e:6f:00:f1:e2:d3:c4:b5:a6:e2:f3:fe (DSA)&#xa;2048 fa:eb:dc:cd:be:af:a0:75:65:8a:52:7d:11:22:33:44 (RSA)" /></port>
```